# Clear interval timer in seconds, a real beginner in Jquery

Tags: jquery, timer, clearinterval

Having some issues trying to clear interval in my code. I just need to stop it as soon as it reaches 0. I've tried setting it inside a function, also, by declaring clearInterval as a variable, but I'm feeling more confused every time as I'm not seeing any errors when console logging. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance. Here is what I'm doing:

```
var timer = 10;
$("#timer").html("Timer");


function timerStart() {
    timer--;
    $("#timer").html(timer);
}

var intervalId = setInterval(timerStart, 1000);

if(timerStart === 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

Comment: you should learn how javascript works first before learning jquery. You need that if statement inside of `timerStart()` method. Otherwise, it will only called once

Comment: yes, I know, I'm learning a lot of new stuff at once, and sometimes simple things got me confused. Thanks for your input though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close!

I made a few changes:

1. Moved the variable declarations together
2. Instead of manually setting the `.html()` for the initial value, just call `timerStart()`. Then you can decrement it afterwards.
3. Do the `timer` check right inside the `timerStart()` method.

```js
    var timer = 10;
    var intervalId = null;

    function timerStart() {
      $("#timer").html(timer);
      if (timer === 0) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
      timer--;
    }

    timerStart();
    intervalId = setInterval(timerStart, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't realized about that. Believe it or not I was stuck with this simple issue for the past hour, I've been learning so much stuff in the last 5 weeks that sometimes I feel I am getting behind in my bootcamp. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    var timer = 10;

    $("#timer").html("Timer");

    var intervalId = setInterval(timerStart, 1000);

    function timerStart() {
      timer--;
      $("#timer").html(timer);
      if(timer == 0) clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
```